# Cannot find the Verifiable Credentials Service Request service principal while creating an access policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/verifiable-credentials/verifiable-credentials-configure-tenant) tutorial to discover and learn more about Entra Verified ID's Verifiable Credentials capabilities. However I'm stuck at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/verifiable-credentials/verifiable-credentials-configure-tenant#set-access-policies-for-the-verifiable-credentials-service-request-service-principal) step. I need to provide access to Verifiable Credentials Service Request service principal but I can't find it in list of principals. I've tried to type the name of the principal and the app ID but I couldn't find it still. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to choose the Verifiable Credentials Service Request service principal after enabling the Verified ID service.